# Trying to search wunderground locations with javascript, jquery, and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, wunderground

The code below doesn't work. Trying to search weather locations. When I search nothing happens.

```
<input type="text" id="query" /><button>search</button><br />
<div id="results">

</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var url='http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?format=JSON&query=';
var query;
    $('button').click(function(){
        query=$("#query").val();
        $.getJSON(url+query,function(json){
            $.each(json.results,function(i,location){
               $("#results").append('<p>'+location.name+'</p>');
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

FYI I am very inexperienced at coding (copied script from another website)

Comment: is autocomplete.wunderground.com the domain of the same site from where your page is served?

Comment: Where did you get this snippet from?

Comment: Parth, no. Bazmega, http://webhole.net/2009/11/28/how-to-read-json-with-javascript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make cross domain request, you have to that with `JSONP`, and you should append callback function for JSONP request as mentioned [here in wunderground.com](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/documentation.html), try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?format=JSON&query=';
    var query;
    $('button').click(function() {
        query = $("#query").val();
        $.getJSON(url + query + '&cb=callbackfunc', function(json) {
            $.each(json.results, function(i, location) {
                $("#results").append('<p>' + location.name + '</p>');
            });
        });
    });
});​
```

**UPDATE:**

At first you should learn what is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

cb parameter is for JSONP callback function in [wunderground API as you can see here in documentation](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/documentation.html).

If you still doesn't understand why you need to use jsonp callback function,

open these two links, and you will see what is the differences between them.

[without cb paramater](http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?format=JSON&query=atina)

[with cb paramater](http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?format=JSON&query=atina&cb=mycallbackfunc)

Comment: Sorry, not good with coding, what should the value of &cb= be?

Comment: @ocanal, Thanks a lot for the information above, the links to [without cd, with cb] are the same really, can u tell what is the difference please?

Comment: @shireefkhatab yes, there is just only one difference, json is wrapped with `mycallbackfunc` when you use callback parameter. that means function is called when jsonp request done. if you have a mycallbackfunc in your page, that will be called with a json parameter. jquery handle jsonp request so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: can u give a hint what would cb look like please?

Comment: @shireefkhatab, here is a simple jsonp request with pure javascript, http://jsfiddle.net/j8h6jomb/7/

Comment: Apprecisted!,  I`m trying to pull the data through $http with angularjs, and i get this error:       XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=London. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed access.    Note: i use live-server or browser-sync as a server

Comment: @ocanal Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can't pull data from remote sites using JavaScript for security reasons (see [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)).

Work arounds involve CORS (limited browser support, not supported by that service), JSON-P (not obviously supported by that service) and using a proxy on your own server.